# Tikz, tcolorbox overprint issue

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

How to rid of overprint issues using tikz and tcolorbox packages in my tex files?
Please find my MWE file is as below:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{%color, % automatically loaded by overprint
  overprint}

\newtcolorbox{casestudy}{enhanced,boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,colframe=red,colback=yellow,
sharp corners, arc=5pt, rounded corners=southwest,left=9pt,right=0pt,top=5.5pt,bottom=3.8pt,
toptitle=0pt,bottomtitle=0pt,lefttitle={0pt},toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,
width=420.56pt,after skip=0pt,before skip=0pt,
titlerule=0pt,titlerule style={green,line width=0pt},frame hidden,
}


\definecolor{mg}{cmyk}{0,1,0,0}
\definecolor{cn}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
\definecolor{bk}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}

\begin{document}
\colorbox{mg}{bk test-1}

\colorbox{mg}{bk test-2}

\colorbox{cn}{text}

\colorbox{mg}{text}%

\colorbox{cn}{text}

\bigskip

\begin{casestudy}
Throughout the unit, students will apply the design and development
stages of the problem-solving methodology. They will acquire and apply
the knowledge and skills to work with different data types to create
solutions that can be used to persuade, educate, inform and entertain.
This unit also examines the role of networked information systems
in the communication of data within a global environment and an
exploration of mobile devices.
\end{casestudy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: package `overprinet`, for what you need it? it is not available on CTAN. what is your problem, what you like to obtain?

Comment: I tried below link and copied style file from following site to rid of overprint issues? http://tex.aanhet.net/overprint/

Comment: What is your problem? What would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: This is printer issues, files will not moved with overprint issues, in Acrobat professional PDF when we turnoff black color, white should not appear in the PDF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Update

Here's a very simple overprint implementation for XeLaTeX. It works with (and in fact requires) `pgf`. `tcolorbox` loads `pgf` so this is no problem.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{casestudy}{%
  sharp corners, colback=yellow, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
  before skip=0pt, after skip=0pt, frame empty}

% Simple overprint implementation for XeLaTeX. Does not respect the colour
% stack, so you have to explicitly turn it on and off.
\makeatletter
\special{pdf:obj @spcko << /Type /ExtGState /op false /OP false >>}
\special{pdf:obj @spcop  << /Type /ExtGState /op true /OP true /OPM 1 >>}
\pgf@sys@addpdfresource@extgs@plain{/SPCko @spcko /SPCop @spcop}
\def\overprinton{\special{pdf:literal direct /SPCop gs}}
\def\overprintoff{\special{pdf:literal direct /SPCko gs}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\textcolor{cyan}{Cyan}
\textcolor{magenta}{Magenta}
\textcolor{yellow}{Yellow}
\textcolor{black}{Black}

\colorbox{magenta}{\overprinton text\overprintoff}

\colorbox{cyan}{\overprinton text\overprintoff}

\begin{casestudy}
  \overprinton
  Throughout the unit, students will apply the design and development stages
  of the problem-solving methodology. They will acquire and apply the
  knowledge and skills to work with different data types to create solutions
  that can be used to persuade, educate, inform and entertain. This unit also
  examines the role of networked information systems in the communication of
  data within a global environment and an exploration of mobile devices.
  \overprintoff
\end{casestudy}
\end{document}
```

---

## Original answer

I take it you want to overprint the black text on the coloured screens. You can do this using the `colorspace` package.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[overprint]{colorspace}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{casestudy}{%
  sharp corners, colback=yellow, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
  before skip=0pt, after skip=0pt, frame empty}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{cyan}{Cyan}
\textcolor{magenta}{Magenta}
\textcolor{yellow}{Yellow}
\textcolor{black}{Black}

\colorbox{magenta}{\textoverprint{text}}

\colorbox{cyan}{\textoverprint{text}}

\begin{casestudy}
  \overprintstate{1}%
  Throughout the unit, students will apply the design and development stages
  of the problem-solving methodology. They will acquire and apply the
  knowledge and skills to work with different data types to create solutions
  that can be used to persuade, educate, inform and entertain. This unit also
  examines the role of networked information systems in the communication of
  data within a global environment and an exploration of mobile devices.
\end{casestudy}
\end{document}
```

#### Composite output

[image: Composite output]

#### Cyan plate

[image: Cyan plate]

#### Magenta plate

[image: Magenta plate]

#### Yellow plate

[image: Yellow plate]

#### Black plate

[image: Black plate]

Comment: following errors shown while compiling above document. (./colorspace.sty
Package: colorspace 2019/03/25 v1.3 PDF color spaces

! Undefined control sequence.
l.561 \immediate\spc@Obj
                        {<< /Type /ExtGState /op false /OP false >>}%

Comment: @DavidPurton I get no error.

Comment: @RajeshN, if it works for Ulrike, then check to make sure your TeX distribution is up to date. `colorspace` 1.3 is the latest version.

Comment: In PDFLaTeX, tcolorbox output hidden. we using XeLaTeX which shows an undefined control sequence as shown above error.

Comment: @RajeshN, OK. That's your problem. `colorspace` does not support XeLaTeX.

Comment: Ok, can you please let us know what version of latex you have used, it will helping us to resolve overprint issues

Comment: @RajeshN, the code above will work with LuaLaTeX or PDFLaTeX and an update TeX system. It will **not** work with XeLaTeX. I'll try and provide an alternative solution for you.

Comment: I tried both MiKTeX and TeXLive using PDFLaTeX engine both are yellowbox completely disappear, please let us know version and latex engine that you have used?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96209/discussion-between-rajesh-n-and-david-purton).

Comment: You could probably with xelatex do `\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{\special{pdf:code /SPCop gs}}}` to activate it on all pages.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, this does work, but I would not recommend doing this. If you ever have white text on a coloured screen it will overprint instead of knock out. There's always a chance this might be missed in checking :). (I know in theory this should be found in preflight, but better safe than sorry.)

Comment: @DavidPurton Such a nice suggestion, also greetings to Ulrike too....

Comment: Thank you everyone, we got required output using XeLaTeX engine.

Comment: Wonderful solution given to us, Thank you for spending your valuable time, once again TeX proved "TeX made easy".

Answer (score 3):

You should load xcolor with the cmyk option so that the default color color is cmyk:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage[overprint]{colorspace}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{casestudy}{enhanced,boxrule=0pt,boxsep=0pt,colframe=red,colback=yellow,
sharp corners, arc=5pt, rounded corners=southwest,left=9pt,right=0pt,top=5.5pt,bottom=3.8pt,
toptitle=0pt,bottomtitle=0pt,lefttitle={0pt},toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,
width=420.56pt,after skip=0pt,before skip=0pt,
titlerule=0pt,titlerule style={green,line width=0pt},frame hidden,
}


\definecolor{mg}{cmyk}{0,1,0,0}
\definecolor{cn}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
\definecolor{bk}{cmyk}{0,0,0,1}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{mg}{bk test-2}

\colorbox{mg}{bk test-2}

\begin{casestudy}
Throughout the unit, students will apply the design and development
stages of the problem-solving methodology. They will acquire and apply
the knowledge and skills to work with different data types to create
solutions that can be used to persuade, educate, inform and entertain.
This unit also examines the role of networked information systems
in the communication of data within a global environment and an
exploration of mobile devices.
\end{casestudy}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please advise that is the `\usepackage[overprint]{colorspace}` works in all types of TeX, i.e., `LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf`, `PDFLaTeX`, `XeLaTeX`, etc.?

Comment: @MadyYuvi colorspace works only for pdflatex and lualatex. It uses colorstacks and I don't know if it is possible to extend it to xelatex. dvips could work with `\special{ps:true setoverprint}` (untested).

Comment: Thanks a lot Ulrike....